# scrollTo() method doesn't work right with Android when adding parameters

Tags: android, jquery, html, scroll

I have this code, where `goUp` is a button and `div1` is where I want to scroll when the button is pushed:

```
$("#goUp").on('click', function(){
var offsetImg = $("#div1").offset(); 
    window.scrollTo(0,offsetImg.top);
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QSJZw/1/

It works right, and I have in production, but when I go with Android it doesn't work, just scrolls to the top of the page (the `div1` tag is not at the top in the web page). But works if I pass a number instead of the second argument `window.scrollTo(0,70);`. I can't test in development with Android, so I want help to find out the issue.

My first guess was that `offsetImg.top` was not got like an integer, but it should.
Maybe I could try `parseInt(offsetImg.top)`, but it seems to have no-sense here.

After looking at other questions, I've seen that probably it is a rendering issue. However, the `scrollTo()` method is called before an Ajax call (just after `e.preventDefault();`), when all the content is loaded. And the content of `div1` is not changing.

Any idea of what can be happening here?

You can try at http://itransformer.es . If you attach an image, when doing a transformation an submit, the window should scroll to the top of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Untested (don't have an Android phone) but try replacing `window` with `$(document)` and use `scrollTop()` method instead of `scrollTo()`:

```
$("#goUp").on('click', function(){
    var offsetImg = $("#div1").offset(); 
    $(document).scrollTop(offsetImg.top);
})
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/QSJZw/3/

Comment: I like your idea. I'll try and come back.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but doesn't work. If you want (and have an Android) you can try. I've updated my answer

Comment: I tried the jsfiddle/3 on Android 4.2 and it worked. ([tried it here](https://www.manymo.com/emulators))

Comment: Yes, my web page is working right too. But not in my Android.